# how to make auto 777 to the folder/files with get created automatically in amazon linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

how to make auto 777 to the folder/files with get created automatically in amazon linux

every time my laravel application creates a new file in temp folder but not able to execute.
how to set automatically to give 777 permision to all files automatically
everytime in have to change the permissions to make it execute .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
chmod -R 777 /path/to/folder
```

with SSH on your server. Every created file in the folder should now inherit these permissions.

Be careful that giving all permissions to a folder is generally a bad idea, it can end up in a security issue. See [this article](https://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2012/09/the-chmod-777-trap-how-and-why-to-avoid-it/).